# how to make a drowdown when icon clicked in angular html sass

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble creating an icon that when clicked appear a dropdown attached just next to the icon. Im using html/sass and typescript (angular):

This is how it should look:

[image of how it should look and work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9uXE.png)

Ty ty very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [official angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) component for menus like yours.

Just change some styles as you need and that's it